# Why can't I use 'django-admin.py makemessages -l cn'

Tags: python, django

print :

```
D:\zjm_code\register2>python D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-adm
in.py makemessages -l cn
Error: This script should be run from the Django SVN tree or your project or app
 tree. If you did indeed run it from the SVN checkout or your project or applica
tion, maybe you are just missing the conf/locale (in the django tree) or locale
(for project and application) directory? It is not created automatically, you ha
ve to create it by hand if you want to enable i18n for your project or applicati
on.
```

2.i made a locale directory ,and

```
D:\zjm_code\register2>python D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-adm
in.py makemessages -l cn
processing language cn
Error: errors happened while running xgettext on __init__.py
'xgettext' 不是内部或外部命令，也不是可运行的程序
或批处理文件。

D:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py:234: RuntimeWarning
: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception
  sys.exit(1)
```

3.
ok

http://hi.baidu.com/zjm1126/blog/item/f28e09deced15353ccbf1a82.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. is `register2` your project or app tree?
2. did you make directory `register2\\locale`?

Comment: hi,alex,i changed the question,help me to havae a look,please

Comment: @zjm, I apparently solved your original problem with my point 2, now you're getting some completely different error with Chinese characters I can't even read, I can't help (looks like there are non-Ascii parts in your `__init__.py`, if so then I suggest you don't do that -- but that's kind of a guess on my part).

Comment: I have the locale folder created, but I get this error: `CommandError: Error running xgettext. Note that Django internationalization requires GNU gettext 0.15 or newer.` I am not sure whether that can be a new question in itself, but do you have any clue how to install the GNU gettext on Windows? (Google did not really know :[)

Comment: Ok, the answer to the above is to download gettext for Windows and set configure the Windows path accordingly. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#gettext-on-windows